# Product URL Issue after changing product name

Tags: magento2

So, I updated many (thousands) of product names, which in turn updated the URL key for those items.

Example: 
Old Url key: acme-rocket
New URL key: rocket

When I try to go to the new url: www.xyx.com/rocket I get a 404 error.

Comment: did you just change the name or also the url-key?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module to regenerate product new URLs :-
https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

Answer (score -1):

If you update only the names of products that will not automatically change the url keys.

Once an url key is set you have to overwrite it or delete it. In the latter case the url key will be regenerated based on the product's name.